# Specializing The Same Template Definition For Two Different Types

Tags: c++

I am trying to specialize the same template for two different classes in the following way:

```
template <>
struct TemplateClass<A> {
  void method(A x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
};

template <>
struct TemplateClass<B> {
  void method(B x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Is there a way I can rewrite this to avoid the duplication inside the two specialization definitions?

I do not have control over the definition of `TemplateClass`. The particular application I have in mind is specialization of `fmt::formatter` as shown here: 
 https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `struct formatter` in `fmt/core.h`, it has a dummy `typename = void` parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename Char = char, typename Enable = void>
struct formatter
```

This dummy parameter allows you to do SFINAE in specializations:

```
template <typename T>
struct formatter<T, char, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, A> || std::is_same_v<T, B>>>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Hmm the following does not compile for me:
```#include <fmt/core.h>

struct A {
  int val;
};

struct B {
  int val;
};

template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<T, char, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<A> || std::is_same_v<B>>>
{
  constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context ctx) {
    return ctx.end();
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const T& x, FormatContext& ctx) {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", x.val);
  }
};```

Comment: while the non dummy parameter duplicated version does compile.

the error I see is long, ending in ```/fmt/core.h:1124:39: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const fmt::v6::internal::named_arg<T, char>’
 1124 |   return arg_mapper<Context>().map(val);
```

Comment: Ah got it - your code should be `std::is_same_v<T, A>` and not `std::is_same_v<A>`. after that change everything works as desired. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only duplication you could avoid in your presented code is the std::cout << std::endl; You are outputting 'x' in both but they are of two different types so that is hardly duplication. If the duplication were actually enough to be concerned over you could create a shared base and have both specializations derive from that.

Comment: The presented code is of course simplified - the real code is much longer, and very duplicated - the only difference between the two versions is the name of the type.